# Setup Apache to run the same site, some parts with Django and some parts with RoR

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, apache-2.2, ruby

I want to setup a website, say http://example.com so that requests to http://example.com/a/<...> would run on a RoR app and http://example.com/b/<...> would run in a Django app.

Is it possible to configure Apache this way? How?

Would it be better to run such a site on Nginx instead because of the memory overheads involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache can be configured at the directory level.  As RoR and Django are both frameworks, it is possible to setup a website the way you want to.

The Django documentation gives a good example of how to configure Apache at the document level:

In the end, your virtual host file should look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.example.com
    <Location "/something">
        Ror setup ...
    </Location>

    <Location "/otherthing">
        Django setup ...
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) allows running Rails, Rack, and [WSGI](https://github.com/kwe/passenger-django-wsgi-example/tree/django) apps.